# syntax error in print statement but syntaticly code is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I run this code:

```
x, y, z, n = (int(input() for i in range(4))
print ([[a,b,c] for a in range(0,x+1)
                for b in range(0,y+1) 
                for c in range(0,z+1) if a + b + c != x])
```

I am getting syntax error in print statement(2nd line),

but if I run this code:

```
x, y, z, n = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
print ([[a,b,c] for a in range(0,x+1) 
                for b in range(0,y+1) 
                for c in range(0,z+1) if a + b + c != n ])
```

it is running without error.

can't understand what I am missing with the syntax, please help

Comment: Spend more days in reading about Python. In particular read its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)

Comment: For starters, balance the parentheses on the first line.

Comment: If the interpreter says you have a syntax error, then you do. The interpreter is *always* right about that. You will find it easier to find errors if you don't start from the assumption (which is clear from your topic header) that your code is correct and the interpeter is somehow mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly balance parenthesis and square brackets in your first line (the "offending" example):

```
x, y, z, n = [int(input()) for i in range(4)]
```

This is a list comprehension, so you need to put it inside []. Also, since you want integer values in *x*, *y*, *z* and *n*, you are correctly using the `int()` constructor, but failing to close the parenthesis after `input()`.

With that corrected, it works without a glitch.

Hope this helps.